# Php query to compare and check from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a query from two tables. First table is offers and the second table is suppliers.

```
offers table
id | supplier_id | updated_at (date field)
 1        3         18-05-2018
 2        1         01-01-2018

suppliers table
id   | name   | contact_email
 1     sujith   sujith@sujith.com
 2     naveen   naveen@naveen.com
 3     sanju    sanj@sanj.com
```

The actual scenario is if there is no offer from a supplier for last 2 Months then list of email address has to be shown. As per the tables data shown above, the Out put should be:

```
 sujith@sujith.com
 naveen@naveen.com
```

Both this email id's has no offer in the table for last 2 Months.

i tried this query, but showing wrong data:

```
   SELECT offers.id, offers.supplier_id, offers.updated_at
  suppliers.name, suppliers.contact_email FROM offers
  INNER JOIN suppliers ON offers.supplier_id = suppliers.id
  WHERE (offers.updated_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

Can anyone pls help me on this.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution it's this query:

```
SELECT suppliers.email 
FROM suppliers LEFT OUTER JOIN offers
ON offers.supplier_id = suppliers.id
WHERE offers.updated_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
      OR offers.updated_at IS NULL;
```

You can check the Build Schema & the Run Query in this [**LINK**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd3453/11)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this, but following should work.

```
SELECT 
offers.id, 
offers.supplier_id, 
offers.updated_at,
suppliers.name, 
suppliers.contact_email 
FROM 
suppliers
LEFT JOIN 
offers
ON offers.supplier_id = suppliers.id
WHERE 
offers.updated_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) 
OR offers.updated_at IS NULL
```